# pptpd dont work on Ubuntu VPS in Azure

Tags: ubuntu, azure, ppp

I have set up a pptpd running on an Ubuntu instance in Azura.
When iám trying to connect from a client the connection times out.
It seems to me that it has something to do with the GRE protocol, maybe it isnt supported in Azure?

Port 1723 open
The same server setup but in AWS works perfect!

From the server log;

```
Jun 12 00:05:06 ubuntu01eus pppd[1258]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jun 12 00:05:06 ubuntu01eus pppd[1258]: Using interface ppp0
Jun 12 00:05:06 ubuntu01eus pppd[1258]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Jun 12 00:05:06 ubuntu01eus pptpd[1257]: GRE: Bad checksum from pppd.
Jun 12 00:05:36 ubuntu01eus pptpd[1257]: CTRL: EOF or bad error reading ctrl packet length.
Jun 12 00:05:36 ubuntu01eus pptpd[1257]: CTRL: couldn't read packet header (exit)
Jun 12 00:05:36 ubuntu01eus pptpd[1257]: CTRL: CTRL read failed
Jun 12 00:05:36 ubuntu01eus pptpd[1257]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[1258]
Jun 12 00:05:36 ubuntu01eus pppd[1258]: Hangup (SIGHUP)
Jun 12 00:05:36 ubuntu01eus pppd[1258]: Modem hangup
Jun 12 00:05:36 ubuntu01eus pppd[1258]: Connection terminated.
Jun 12 00:05:36 ubuntu01eus pppd[1258]: Exit.
Jun 12 00:05:36 ubuntu01eus pptpd[1257]: CTRL: Client xx.230.xxx.248 control connection finished
```

/J

Answer (score 2):

pptp requires both TCP and GRE (IP protocol 47). Windows Azure only supports TCP and UDP right now.

What is the scenario you are trying to achieve? Windows Azure offers a few connectivity solutions such as Azure Connect, and Azure virtual network, maybe one of them can serve your needs.

Comment: I like to setup a gateway to access US only sites from where iám living. Hope to se support for GRE in Azure in the future until then AWS will do.

Comment: You could setup an SSTP gateway instead.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

The reason is that Azure do not route GRE packets between on-premises and Azure Virtual Network.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure completely however does this feature needed support for Virtual Network in Ubuntu VM? During preview, Windows Azure Virtual Machine for Linux does not support Virtual networking.

So If that is the case it could be your root cause. IF you need to get much better assistance I would suggest asking your question directly at Windows Azure Virtual Machines for Linux support forum so  you can get exact feedback from respective team. The supported forum link is here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforLinux/threads